# Antlr Mutual Left Recursion

Tags: recursion, antlr, antlr4

I would like to parse something like

```
f()[3]()[3] ... () or []
```

meaning fucntions that return arrays, which can be referenced and may contain functions themselves.

I tried

```
functionCall: (ID | arrayReference) '(' expressionList? ')';
arrayReference: (ID | functionCall) '[' arithmeticExpression ']';
```

but get mutual recursion errors. Is there an easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
value
  : value '[' arithmeticExpression ']' # arrayReference
  | value '(' expressionList? ')' # functionCall
  | ID #id
  ;
```